# Can Schematron support parameters?

Tags: xslt, schematron

I am trying to pass in several parameters to a scheatron xlst transform, I can declare local variables and read from a file but that still means that I am either hard-coding or using a relative path to the execution location.

Does anyone know of a way to pass in a parameter, something like this is what I really need:

```
     <xsl:param name="doctype"/>
     <xsl:param name="id"/>
```

Any suggestion is welcome, or do I give up on schematron and go back to standard xslt?

Peter